# Why it shows Cannot access offset of type string on string error?

Tags: php, laravel

This dump     `dd($post['comments']);` shows the content below:

```
^ "[{"key": "o0Gdz1EsxOpOLN", "layout": "comment", "attributes": {"title": "a", "comment": "b"}}]"
```

Then this data is being transformed like this:

```
  [
                    'name' => "comments",
                    'data' => [
                        'comments' =>
                        collect($post['comments'])->map(function ($comment) {
                            return [
                                'title' => $comment['attributes']['title'],
                                'message' => $comment['attributes']['message'],
                            ];
                        }),
                    ]
                ],
```

But it shows an error:

```
Cannot access offset of type string on string
```

The error seems that its here:

```
                            'title' => $comment['attributes']['title'],
```

Do you know what can be the issue?

Comment: Looks like your `comments` are in json format. You might have to add `json_decode` to it before trying to access it as an array.

Comment: Or if `comments` is db column in `posts` table, you can include `comments` in the `protected $casts` array. [ref](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `json_decode()` to access the data.

```
[
    'name' => "comments",
    'data' => [
        'comments' =>
            collect(json_decode($post['comments'], true))->map(function ($comment) {
                return [
                    'title' => $comment['attributes']['title'],
                    'message' => $comment['attributes']['message'],
                ];
            }),
    ]
],
```

But you should test it before hand that the content of `$post['comments']` contain the json data structure you need.

Comment: Thanks! What you mean with test it?

Comment: @Bernard if the data is coming from a request: either you're sending your data with the wrong header (should be json-applicatoin)  or you blindly believe that the format will never have issues. You should set some validation rules in place either way to not trigger errors on execution.

Comment: @Bernard if your data is from database, you can set up auto casting on the field "comment" https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting